# How to Delete an Upload Destination?

Tags: file-uploads, file-manager

I want to delete an empty upload destination in ExpressionEngine, but can't find the appropriate option. Would be grateful if someone knowledgeable could point out the button I should click to get rid of the upload destination I don't need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just goto the Content menu > Files > File Upload Preferences

This will list the upload destinations. Then to the far right of the list, you will see a delete column, just click the Trash icon for the destination you want to delete.

This will delete the destination in EE but not the folder containing the files.